# Need to dissect this program! (Reverse the Array)

Tags: ruby

I'm not really understanding the `rev=false` portion which comes after `def alphabetize`:

```
def alphabetize (arr, rev=false)
```

or the portion:

```
if rev
```

If someone can explain it to me in simple terms that'd be great.  When I 
search this question up it pops up with help as far as how it works which I understand, however I don't get `arr=false` or the last line.

```
puts "Z-A: #{alphabetize(books, true)}"
```

I'm sure those learning thru CodeAcademy would appreciate the answer. This is the code for reference.

```
def alphabetize (arr, rev=false)
  if rev
    arr.sort { |item1, item2| item2 <=> item1 }
  else
    arr.sort { |item1, item2| item1 <=> item2 }
  end
end

books = ["Heart of Darkness", "Code Complete", "The Lorax","The Prophet", "Absalom"]

puts "A-Z: #{alphabetize(books)}"
puts "Z-A: #{alphabetize(books, true)}"
```

Comment: Its not the same question. The one I had asked has completely different coding and isn't as coherent. Please take off the mark of it being a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

rev=false - this is just a default value for rev so you can call the function with or without a second parameter.

#{} - used in a string allows you to escape the string this means it executes the code inbetween the curly brackets this would be the same as "Z-A: " + alphabetize(books, true)

Comment: can you simplify the (books, true) please? You're saying that it it takes the books portion so if it takes it as true does it then negate the y portion of it? How does true make it go backwards?

Comment: It means calling alphabetize(books) is the same as calling alphabetize(books, false). The function itself sorts the books are you pass it if rev is true it inverses the array otherwise not

Answer (score 0):

The `def foo(bar="baz", c=4)` syntax is called "default arguments". It means that if there is no argument passed to the function, the argument will take the default value. For example, in `foo("boo")`, you've passed `bar` to be `"boo"`, but since you haven't passed a value for `c`, it will be `4`, by default.

The idea of default arguments is also present with keyword arguments. The differences between keyword arguments and default arguments are discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368051/default-value-vs-keyword-argument).

Comment: Again I just asked for it to be simple using my example. I understand its a default argument but this isn't coherent man. I appreciate the help of course but if you can simplify it that'd be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

That is a way of setting default parameters for you function in case you don't pass one, for eg

```
def add(a, b, format=true)
  if format
    "a + b = #{a+b}"
  else
    a+b
  end
end
```

in the example above you can either call the function `add` with or without the `format` value, if you just call it as `add(2,3)` the value of `format` will be true but you can chose to set format off by doing `add(2,3,false)`

**EDIT 1**

In your example, when you do `puts "A-Z: #{alphabetize(books)}"` you are not passing the second argument, so in the `alphabetize` function, `rev` gets the default `false` value and so it goes to else block and returns you `arr.sort { |item1, item2| item1 <=> item2 }`

but, when you call the method with a second argument as in `puts "Z-A: #{alphabetize(books, true)}"` you are passing `true` which overwrites the default value of `rev` in the method so now since `rev` is true it goes into the if block and returns you `arr.sort { |item1, item2| item2 <=> item1 }`.

Hope it helps

Comment: Can you just explain with my example please? So if rev but how would it turn to be false?

Comment: updated my answer, see if it helps @WilkeJones